# Confusion on SUEXEC and DOCROOT

Tags: apache-2.2, suexec

I keep running into an issue with suexec where it says the cgi script is not in the docroot.

I get this error:

```
"[2012-05-21 04:53:02]: command not in docroot (/apps/dctools/www/cgi-bin/test.cgi)"
```

I have a symbolic link to where the cgi files are. Are symlinks a problem with suexec?

Using virtual host config.

```
apache docroot:  /var/www/html
suexec docroot: /var/www
```

**virtual host config**

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.1.1:80>
     ServerAdmin me@nowhere.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dctools
     ServerName dctools.nowhere.com
     ErrorLog logs/dctools.nowhere.com-error_log
     CustomLog logs/dctools.nowhere.com-access_log common
     SuexecUserGroup me white
     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/dctools/"
     <Directory "/var/www/dctools/cgi-bin">
       AllowOverride None
       Options None
       Options FollowSymlinks
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**symlink setup**

```
-sh-3.2$ pwd
/var/www/html

-sh-3.2$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 May 14 21:06 dctools -> /apps/dctools/www

-sh-3.2$ pwd
/var/www/cgi-bin

-sh-3.2$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root 21 May 14 21:47 dctools -> /apps/dctools/cgi-bin
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual location of the file, not the symlink, is what determines whether `suexec` will run it.  That setting is compiled into `suexec` and to change it would require recompiling it.  By default that would be at `/var/www` which you already mentioned is your configuration.  That means that you would need to either recompile `suexec` to allow `/app` to be the accepted root for `suexec` or you would need to move/copy the actual files within the configured `suexec` root.

Comment: Does this mean (in my case after a system update) that Perl files in /home/username/cgi-bin/ or deeper will no longer run with suexec under Apache2.2? They were fine previously…